# Java Script input issue

Tags: javascript

Here is my code,

```js
var arr = new Array(10);
var index = 0;
var i = new Array(10);

for (i[index] = document.getElementById("in").value; index < arr.length; index++) {
  arr[index] = i[index];
}

document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = arr;
}
```

```html
<button id="but">click</button>
<input id="in" />
<p id="para">hello</p>
```

I am not getting the desired output.
the input value is not being displayed.
so what kind of changes should i make in this code to get the desired output.
also i want my empty array(arr) to get 10 different input values which i type 10 times after the previous input is displayed.
please help me to solve above issue.
will this work with js only or should i use other language.

Comment: your input doesn't even have a type

Comment: @Enjoyted: `input` elements [have a default type: `text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type)

Comment: i have a button tag there with id "but"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder didn't know. have never seen an input written without any so I never asked myself the result without one lol. thanks for the info anyhows

Comment: You probably want to put that `for` loop *inside* the `onclick` function.

Comment: If I do that, my input is being displayed as the first element of array.

Comment: @SriHarsha, is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/tdusfog8/1/

Comment: @nevermind, thankyou very much.